# IPN - Handle empty string

Tags: php, url, paypal, paypal-ipn

working with paypal´s IPN i do this:

```
$variable1 = "string";
$variable2 = "";
$test = array('cmd'=>'_xclick',
                        'business'=>'email@email.com',
                        'notify_url'=> 'url/to/ipn-script',
                        'item_name'=>'product',
                        'amount'=>'1.00',
                        'currency_code'=>'USD',
                        'lc'=>'US',
                        'custom'=>serialize( array( "variable1" => $variable1,"variable2" => $variable2)));

                        $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?".http_build_query($test);

                        header("Location:".$url);
                        exit();
```

Using this code i get this error:

```
Failure: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL,'.',NULL)'
```

Can i send empty strings in url and handle them in ipn-script or not?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a MySQL error not a PayPal error?

From your script I cannot tell what queries might be executing. Try and replace 'custom' with a blank value and see if the error goes away, if you believe that is the culprit.

As a side note keep in mind the custom variable has a 200 character limit IIRC.

Comment: hi :) so custom cant be longer than 200 characters? are there any possibilities to get more than 200 chara´s passed? greetings